# xcode: run application unit tests on device, breakpoint doesn't hit

Tags: xcode

I added an application unit tests target, when I run it on simulator, works well and I can debug the test cases.But when I run it on device,breakpoint doesn't hit. So my question is:how can I debug application unit tests when I run it on device?

My environment:xcode:4.3.3 device:5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I just cleared all my logs,deleted my breakpoint, quit xcode, and then restarted computer.Then I re added the break point. Did that work for you?